# expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType for subprocess of ffmpeg

Tags: django, ffmpeg, subprocess, typeerror

I dont know much about **ffmpeg**, **subprocess** and its functions, im trying to take a **screenshot** form a video and **save** it at my other field of my model.
this is my model:

```
class SubSong(models.Model):
song = models.ForeignKey(SongPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='related_song')
create = jmodels.jDateField(auto_now_add=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='related_user')
video = models.FileField(upload_to='sub_video/',)
like = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, )
total_like = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
is_allowed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
image_sub = ThumbImage(upload_to='sub_songs/', default='1.jpg')

def __str__(self):
    return self.song.title
```

and **views.py**

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
    authen(request)
    form = MyTryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.cleaned_data
        x = SubSong.objects.create(song_id=id,
                                   user_id=request.user.id,
                                   video=data['video'], )
        path = x.video.name
        out = path.replace('sub_video/', '').replace('mp4', 'jpg')
        z=subprocess.check_output(
            ffmpeg.input('media/' + path, ss='00:00:50').filter(
                'thumbnail').output('media/sub_songs/' + out, vframes=1).run(), text=True)
        x.image_sub=z
        x.save()
        messages.success(request, 'ویدیوی شما با موفقیت ارسال شد ، پس از بررسی منتشر خواهد شد')
        return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

    else:
        messages.error(request, 'ویدیوی شما بارگداری نشد')
        return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

it can save the **video** and also default picture *1.jpg* at **image_sub**. also it can save scrrenshot at the **media/sub_song/**.but my problem is that it gives me error:
**expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType**
how i should return the **screen** from **subprocess** to save it as my **image_sub** field? and why do this error raise? i dont want to see this error again

Comment: hi guys i solve it by myself. i had used ffmpeg_python package and it dosnt need subprocess.checkout and z. so i removed them ! for saveing in my field i just gave the outputpath with out 'media/'.   

        (
            ffmpeg.input('media/' + path, ss='00:00:50').filter(
                'thumbnail').output('media/sub_songs/' + out, vframes=1).run(), text=True)
        x.image_sub='sub_songs/'+out